# Retornar Grupo de atributo de uma categoria específica

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo 3 tabelas: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08b79f)

tb_atributos, tb_atr_to_prod, tb_atr_to_cat.

A Tabela TB_ATRIBUTOS possui todos os atributos pais e filhos. 
A Tabela TB_ATR_TO_PROD possui todos os atributos com seus respectivos produtos.
A Tabela TB_ATR_TO_CAT possui o código da categoria que representa um certo grupo de atributos.
Eu preciso criar uma lista de todos os atributos de uma certa categoria, parecida com essa:

```
<h3>Cor</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Verde</li>
  <li>Azul</li>
  <li>Preto</li>
</ul>

<h3>Cone</h3>
<ul>
  <li>2.500M</li>
  <li>3.000M</li>
  <li>1.000M</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue nova select, com as restrições que você informou nos comentários. Veja se resolve sua questão.

```
SELECT r.*, cat.id_cat
  FROM (  SELECT a.id AS id_pai,
                 '1 - Categoria' AS rotulo,
                 a.nome_atributo AS valor
            FROM tb_atributo a
           WHERE id_pai = 0
           UNION
           SELECT b.id_pai, 
                 '2 - Atributo' AS rotulo,
                  b.nome_atributo AS valor
             FROM tb_atributo b
            WHERE b.id_pai <> 0  ) AS r
 INNER JOIN tb_atr_to_cat cat ON r.id_pai = cat.id_atr
 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                    a.id_pai
               FROM tb_atr_to_prod p
              INNER JOIN tb_atributo a ON p.id_atr = a.id) ap ON r.id_pai = ap.id_pai
 WHERE cat.id_cat = 115
 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Infelizmente não consegui testar no sqlfiddle. Me retorne após seus testes.

> RESPOSTA ANTERIOR

Amigo, segue uma solução que retorna uma lista conforme seu exemplo:

```
SELECT r.*
  FROM (  SELECT a.id,
                 '1 - Categoria' AS rotulo,
                 a.nome_atributo AS valor
            FROM tb_atributo a
           WHERE id_pai = 0
           UNION
           SELECT b.id_pai, 
                 '2 - Atributo' AS rotulo,
                  b.nome_atributo AS valor
             FROM tb_atributo b
            WHERE b.id_pai <> 0  ) AS r
 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Basta utilizar a coluna `rotulo` da *SELECT* e montar uma lógica de exibição na sua página `PHP`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara deu certo!! Só que eu precisava retornar os grupos que contém produtos (tb_atr_to_prod) E também retornar os grupos de uma certa categoria (tb_atr_to_cat). Mas beleza, vou tentar implementar aqui! Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Que bom amigo. Se não conseguir implementar atualiza o sqlfiddle que depois dou uma olhada pra você! Até!

Comment: Emerson, o sqlfiddle ja está atualizado :)

Comment: Felipe, select atualizada, verifique.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro executei esta query para trazer sua lista completa e analisar sua requisição:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    prd.id_prod as ID_PRODUTO,
    att.id as ID_ATRIBUTO,
    att.id_pai,
    att.nome_atributo,
    prd.id AS ID_TAB_PRD
FROM
    tb_atributo att
        LEFT JOIN
    tb_atr_to_prod prd ON (prd.id_atr = att.id)
WHERE
    prd.id IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY att.id , prd.id_prod
```

Porém, para você fazer o que pretende, você precisa utilizar uma técnica chamada PIVOT:

[**Aqui tem um exemplo simples**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8332c/122)

[**E aqui um exemplo, mais complexo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8332c/23)